# git move directory to another repository while keeping the history

Tags: git

First - apologies for asking this question. There are a lot of topics about it already. But I'm not having much luck with them. My lack of familiarity with git is not much help.

I'm moving a folder from one git repo to another (which already exists). e.g.

```
repo-1
---- dir1
---- dir2
---- dir3
---- dir-to-move
---- dir5

repo-2
---- dir1
---- dir2
---- dir3
```

In the end I want the repos to look like

```
repo-1
---- dir1
---- dir2
---- dir3
---- dir-to-move
---- dir5

repo-2
---- dir1
---- dir2
---- dir3
---- dir-to-move
```

i.e. For a time *dir-to-move* will exist in both repos. But eventually I'll migrate the latest changes to *repo-2* and remove *dir-to-move* from *repo-1*.

My initial research made me believe that I needed to use *filter-branch*. e.g.

[How to move files from one git repo to another preserving history using `git format-patch`and `git am`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830916/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-preserving-history-using-git-for)

I've since learnt that *subtree* superseded that approach. However it's not doing what I expected. I thought I'd be able to do something like

In *repo-1* workspace

```
git subtree split -P dir-to-move -b split
```

to filter the *split* branch down to only *dir-to-move* and it's history.
Then in *repo-2* workspace

```
git remote add repo-1 repo-1-url.git
git subtree add --prefix dir-to-move split
```

This does move the code across. It also, sort of, includes the history

e.g.

```
cd repo-2
git log
```

Shows commits from *repo-1*

but

```
cd repo-2
git log dir-to-move
```

Shows only an 'Add dir-to-move from commit ....'

i.e. The history is included but does not show up when checked for the specific files/directories.

How can I do this properly?

Comment: looks like git fails to follow directory move. If you specify some file instead of the directory, does it follow its move?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I can't help you with `git subtree`, but with `filter-branch` it's possible.

First you need to create a common repository that will contain both source and destination branches. This can be done by adding a new "remote" beside "origin" and fetching from the new remote.

Use `filter-branch` on the source branch to `rm -rf` all directories except `dir-to-move`. After that you'll have a commit history that can be cleanly rebased or merged into the destination branch. I think the easiest way is to `cherry-pick` all non-empty commits from the source branch. The list of these commits can be obtained by running `git rev-list --reverse source-branch -- dir-to-move`

Of course, if the history of `dir-to-move` is non-linear (already contains merge commits), then it won't be preserved by cherry-pick, so `git merge` can be used instead.

Example create common repo:

```
cd repo-2
git remote add source ../repo-1
git fetch source
```

Example filter branch

```
cd repo-2
git checkout -b source-master source/master
CMD="rm -rf dir1 dir2 dir3 dir5"
git filter-branch --tree-filter "$CMD"
```

Example cherry-pick into destination master

```
cd repo-2
git checkout master
git cherry-pick `git rev-list --reverse source-master -- dir-to-move`
```

Comment: Appears to be the only solution. I followed the approach here http://blog.mattsch.com/2015/06/19/move-directory-from-one-repository-to-another-preserving-history/

Comment: Notably, if the contents of `dir-to-move` were ever previously moved within repo-1, this solution will truncate the history of those files to only as long as they've existed in the `dir-to-move` location within repo-1.

Comment: For anyone coming here in 2021 or later, note that in the last couple of years, git convention has changed to use `main` instead of `master`, so you may need to replace occurrences of `master` with `main` in the code of this answer.

Comment: `git fetch source --no-tags`, if you don't want to pull in tags from repo-1.

Comment: error: commit <SHA1> is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed

Answer (score 75):

This is indeed possible using `git subtree`.

In repo-1 create a subtree:

```
git subtree split -P dir-to-move -b <split>
```

The `split` branch will now only contain the `dir-to-move` directory.
You now need to pull the branch from repo-1 into a branch in repo-2.

In case repo-2 happens to be a new repository (e.g. just after `git init`) Things are as easy as checking out a branch with no history and pulling from repo-1.

```
cd repo-2
git checkout <branch>
git pull <path-to-repo-1.git> <split>
```

However if repo-2 is an existing repo where commits have already been made (as is the case in this question), you need to merge from an orphan branch in repo-2:

```
cd repo-2
git checkout --orphan <temp>                    # Create a branch with no history
git pull <path-to-repo-1.git> <split>           # Pull the commits from the subtree
git checkout <branch>                           # Go back to the original branch
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories <temp>    # Merge the unrelated commits back
git branch -d <temp>                            # Delete the temporary branch
```

Comment: That was the most helpful answer for me. I'd like to add that the --allow-unrelated-histories can also just be used on the git pull command directly, which may lead to some merge conflicts if you have the same files in your repo-2 already, but if it's easy to solve those conflicts then this is the fastest solution, imo.

Comment: This worked well for me but lost the parent folder. Found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940679/how-do-i-git-subtree-split-but-maintain-the-full-folder-hierarchy)

Comment: This page works perfect for me: my `repo-2` is a brand new one has no commit

Comment: This is the esiest approcah in my point of view. Even cleaner than the one I knew from https://www.johno.com/move-directory-between-repos-with-git-history

Comment: `git pull <path-to-repo-1.git> <split>` generates the error `fatal: Updating an unborn branch with changes added to the index.` Documentation on the error seems unavailable.

Comment: You can replace the `git pull ...` with `git fetch <path-to-repo-1.git> <split>:<temp>`

Comment: For the fetch command you may need `--update-head-ok` to get around `fatal: refusing to fetch into branch ...` error

Comment: if git pull, I tried inserting an empty commit, and delete after pull, which worked around the error `git commit --allow-empty -m "empty"`

Answer (score 26):

FWIW, the following worked for me after a number of iterations.

Clone both the repos to a temporary work area.

```
git clone <repourl>/repo-1.git 
git clone <repourl>/repo-2.git
cd repo-1
git remote rm origin # delete link to original repository to avoid any accidental remote changes
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter dir-to-move -- --all  # dir-to-move is being moved to another repo.  This command goes through history and files, removing anything that is not in the folder.  The content of this folder will be moved to root of the repo as a result. 
# This folder has to be moved to another folder in the target repo.  So, move everything to another folder.
git filter-branch -f --index-filter \
'git ls-files -s | /usr/local/bin/sed -e "s/\t\"*/&dir-to-move\//" |
    GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
        git update-index --index-info &&
 mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
# Above command will go through history and rewrite the history by adding dir-to-move/ to each files.  As a result, all files will be moved to a subfolder /dir-to-move.  Make sure to use gnu-sed as OSX sed doesn't handle some extensions correctly.  For eg. \t
```

Now switch to target repo and fetch everything from source.

```
git clone repo-2
git remote add master ../repo-1/
git pull master master --allow-unrelated-histories
git push  # push everything to remote
```

Above steps assume that master branches are used for both source and targets.  However, tags and branches were ignored.

Comment: I had problems with this approach on windows + git bash. I replaced the path to `usr\bin` path with the actual `sed` command but I got `Rewrite ... mv: cannot stat `my-repo-local-path/.git-rewrite/t/../index.new': No such file or directory`

Comment: Nice git voodoo for correcting the destination path. Worked flawlessly.

Comment: On macOS I had to tweak `/usr/local/bin/sed -e "s/\t\"*/&dir-to-move\//"` command.
Instead of `/usr/local/bin/sed` just use `sed` and replace `\t` with tab provided with `^`+`V` `Tab`.

Comment: What is the `^+V` `Tab`  I tried `^+V` that does nothing.  Then while holding `^+V` I push `Tab` then it switches to a new different tab.

Comment: You may need adding "--no-ff" flag to the line:
  

    `git pull master master --no-ff --allow-unrelated-histories`

Answer (score 19):

My approach to move `dir-to-move` to `repo 2`. Start by cloning the `repo 1` in a new location and cd to the `repo 1` folder. In my case I am moving the folder from `repo 1` branch `develop` to `repo 2` where `develop` is not existent yet.

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter dir-to-move -- --all     #line 1
git remote -v                                                    #line 2
git remote set-url origin repo_2_remote_url                      #line 3
git remote -v                                                    #line 4
git push origin develop                                          #line 5
```

Explanation for each line:

1. Cleans all commits not related to `dir-to-move`, removes all files outside that folder, moves all contents in the root folder `repo 1`. From [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch):

> Only look at the history which touches the given subdirectory. The result will contain that directory (and only that) as its project root

2. You are still pointing to your origin `repo 1` url
3. Replace the origin url for your current folder to point to `repo 2`
4. Check the URLs have been updated correctly
5. Push to `repo 2` the (newly created, in this case) `develop` branch

You can now clone or pull or fetch your `repo 2` repository. You will have under `repo 2` folder the contents of `dir-to-move` along with relevant history as expected.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it will not move all the remote branches and tags.

Comment: It only moves one branch at a time, you could do this for all your branches manually if you don't find a better way. (But should you have long living branches?!) The tags are basically commit identifiers so there must be an additional command for that too

Comment: It's not about having long living branches but really just remote branches that you have not checked out locally (it might be short lived branches from other people for example). To do that you should do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20793890/43046

Comment: These commands work for me! If possible, could you please share any command/setting by which I can revert my branch-filter changes after pushing to another branch?

Answer (score 10):

Another solution is to use [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) which `git filter-branch` [officially recommends](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#:%7E:text=Please%20use%20an%20alternative%20history%20filtering%20tool%20such%20as%20git%20filter-repo).

Find a full example including hints about the installation for windows users at my answer on how to [push commits affecting a given path to a new origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65265319/298288)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `git format-patch`, followed by `git am`:

```
mkdir /tmp/mergepatchs
cd ~/repo/org
git format-patch -o /tmp/mergepatchs --root dir_to_move1 dir_to_move2 dir_to_move3
cd ~/repo/dest
git am /tmp/mergepatchs/*.patch
```

Thank-you to http://blog.neutrino.es/2012/git-copy-a-file-or-directory-from-another-repository-preserving-history/ for suggesting this approach, and to @sean's comment, below, for improving it :)

Comment: simpler with: `git format-patch -o /tmp/mergepatchs --root $reposrc`

Comment: This worked well for me! One slight change is that I used `git am -3 /tmp/mergepatchs/*.patch` to do a 3-way merge to resolve conflicts. Some docs here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am#Documentation/git-am.txt--3

Comment: Thank you @sean . That seems like it should actually be possible to memorize now :)  (So far, I just google each time, and just copy-paste from here :) )

Answer (score 4):

### Split git monorepo into smaller git repositories

#### (Move git folder from one repo to another while keeping commit history)

```
cd target-repo

git remote add source ../monorepo
git fetch source

# create new branch from source branch (e.g. master)
git checkout -b source source/master

# filter out git history of a single folder only (e.g. ./dir)
FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1 git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter ./dir -- --all

# reapply the commits on top of your target repo history
git rebase master

# create a new Pull Request branch
git checkout master
git checkout -b your_new_branch
git rebase source
```

Now that you have a fresh new repository, it might be a good time to clean-up some unnecessary files from the history before you publish the new `master` branch.

```
FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1 git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf <path_to_file>' HEAD
```

Comment: Working but timestamps of commit history is overwritten

Answer (score 0):

We have two approaches here:

- git filter-branch
- git subtree

I used the former approach from https://www.johno.com/move-directory-between-repos-with-git-history and I found some better simplifications (e.g. Basin's approach is great).

Nevertheless, the later approach is much better and I can point some reasons:

1. "*git filter-branch has a plethora of pitfalls that can produce non-obvious manglings of the intended history rewrite (and can leave you with little time to investigate such problems since it has such abysmal performance). These safety and performance issues cannot be backward compatibly fixed and as such, its use is not recommended.*" - You can read more about the reason why in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch
2. I really disliked the ideia of using **git filter-branch** when I saw it rewrote the whole history of my repo unnecessarily (i.e. **git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter my-dir -- -- all**)
3. When I found **git subtree split -P dir-to-move -b**  which creates a clean branch with only my folder I loved it, so using the approach presented by Thymo really was so clean and I strongly recommend using this approach!

Maybe a need to post a script on githug.

Answer (score -1):

You can even make a commit on `repo-1` by deleting all directory other than `dir-to-move` locally (by this way no need to use `fitler-branch`) and then pull to `repo-2`.

```
git clone https://path/to/repo-1
cd repo-1
rm dir1 dir2 dir3 dir5 -rf
git commit -m "Removed unwanted directory for repo-2
cd ../
git clone https://path/to/repo-2
cd repo-2
git remote add repo-1-src ../repo-1
git pull repo-1-src master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

**Note**: Make sure `git` version is `2.9` or more for using `--allow-unrelated-histories` option

Comment: So, this does work but only does what it says on the tin. Basically the historical commits from `repo-1` leading up to the commit in which everything else got removed will become jammed into your `repo-2`. I reckon this could be used together with `filter-branch` so that repo-2's history stays intact. @donnie and @basin answers are the full package.

Answer (score -11):

dumb manual solution if all other fails:

1. Download all files from first repo
2. Create a new repo
3. Clone the second repo to disk.
4. Unpack the first repo files you want to keep (new structure)
5. Push the changes to second repo.
6. Verify that you have what you want
7. Delete the files/folders from first repo that you dont want.

You lose history however