# Move folder to another git repository and keep the history

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

I would like to move a folder from git to another git repository.

For example:

This is my current folder structure in Git.

```
src/Project/RegistrationBundle
src/Project/PictureGenerationBundle
src/Project/CloudDriveBundle
readme.md
```

I would like to move it to a new repo with the following folder structure but I want to keep the git history from the previous repository:

```
src/RegistrationBundle
readme.md
```

I have tried to run it with git filter-branch

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter src/Project/RegistrationBundle/
```

However, I cannot find a solution to customize the folder structure.

Please let me know if it is achievable.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811986/git-move-directory-to-another-repository-while-keeping-the-history

Comment: Do you want the folder "src/RegistrationBundle" to remain a part of old repo? If  yes, do you want a single change in any file of src/RegistrationBundle to be reflected on both repos ?

Comment: I don't have a complete answer to your question, but it's also worth mentioning that setting the repository move aside, git is [not great at tracking file renames and directory structure changes within a repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history). You may have some luck if you first commit the directory structure change as its own commit in Repo A, then do the migration to Repo B with filter-branch afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your repo architecture on the current local repository (removing the 'Project' folder), commit the change, and then change the remote git repository.

Use `git remote set-url origin <the new git url>` to change the repository url.

The history will be the same one since the local history in the .git folder didn't changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter src/Project/RegistrationBundle/ -- --all
```

when you run this command all you have is the files inside the RegistrationBundle, and then in the new repository add a remote with the path to the RegistrationBundle and then do a git pull

Comment: Your answer came up in review. My comment is a suggestion to improve your answer. Please click "edit" above and add the explanation you've provided. Don't explain it in the comments, since comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: this command has a warning: WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
         rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
         alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
         (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.