# How to move multiple directories from another repo and preserve git log directory behavior?

Tags: git, git-log, git-subtree, git-mv

I've read *several* threads on moving directories between git repositories, and the one I've settled on using is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475), which makes use of `git subtree`.

Following the steps, everything seems to work well, but the problem comes at the end.

I'm left with a new repo where all of the contents of the directory I wanted to move is in the root. If I do a `git mv` of the contents into the subdirectory I want, when I do a `git log -- sub\dir\1`, the history is NOT viewable from there. The history is only visible from the root.

I plan to move multiple directories in this fashion, so it dampers things a bit because now I have to use `git log --follow` on every single file I look up the history for.

Is there another way, or something that I am doing wrong, so that I can preserve the history under the right subdirectory? If it helps, the folder structure I want in my new repo is actually the same as the one in my old repo (well, at least before the `git subtree` command).

To be explicit, here is what I am starting with:

```
\old-repo
   \sub\dir\1
   \sub\dir\2
   \sub\dir\3
```

Here is where I am now:

```
\new-repo (subdir1 history viewable from here)
   \sub\dir\1 (subdir1 history is NOT viewable, besides the most recent git mv)
```

Here is what I actually want:

```
\new-repo
   \sub\dir\1 (subdir1 history viewable from here)
   \sub\dir\2 (subdir2 history viewable from here)
   \sub\dir\3 (subdir3 history viewable from here)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git move directory to another repository while keeping the history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811986/git-move-directory-to-another-repository-while-keeping-the-history)