# How to turn a subfolder of a repository and its mirros from different branches into an independent repository?

Tags: git

Consider that you a have git repository with subfolders:

- `firstFolder`
- `secondFolder`
- `thirdFolder`
- ...

and the repository has multiple branches:

- `firstBranch`
- `secondBranch`
- `thirdBranch`
- ...

And you want to turn, for example, the `firstFolder` and its clones/mirrors across different branches into an independent repository. This is the equivalent of `git checkout` to every one of those branches and `git rm -r` the other folders and then `git mv` the content of that specific folder to the main folder. But I was wondering if there is a more canonical way to do this? One solution would be writing a script to list all the branches and repeat these steps across those; I thought maybe there is a git solution to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git move directory to another repository while keeping the history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811986/git-move-directory-to-another-repository-while-keeping-the-history)

Comment: @Brian It is close, but is not exactly what I need. I don;t want to move a folder to another repository. I just want to turn one subfolder to its own.

Comment: Foad, the process is the same for moving a directory to an empty repository as for moving a directory to an existing repository. Simply checkout the repository, filter-branch to extract the desired directory as described. The only difference between your case and the one describe in the linked question is that you may skip the final cherry-pick step to merge the single-directory repository with the  target repository.

Comment: @Brian Thanks. I will try to understand the solutions on that page and then come bakc here if I had more questions.