# How to move one repo to another repo folder and keep git history?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to move my project(e.g.project-A) to monorepo and keep whole git history. now when adding remote repository to new one with

```
git remote add A <remote-repo-project-A>
```

and pull project with

```
git pull project-A master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

source files are in folder monorepo\src instead of monorepo\apps\project-A\src

Basically I want to move repo-A to new repo with following structure:

```
repo-A
---- src

new repo
---- projects
---- ---repo-A(rename to project-A)
---- ------src
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811986/git-move-directory-to-another-repository-while-keeping-the-history) answer your question?

Comment: I don't understand your question can you try to be a bit more clear.

Comment: @Steezy I want something similar I updated the question...

Comment: @Michael  I apologize for being unclear... I updated the question.  I want to move old project to new repo with this structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

History, in Git, is simply the commits.  The commits *are* the history.  So the literal answer to the question that you didn't quite ask—"can I change the contents of the commits without changing the commits' contents"—is of course *no*.  More importantly, no commit can ever be changed, by anyone or anything, because the commits are *numbered*, and the numbers are cryptographic checksums of their contents.  So if you change anything about a commit, that changes the *number*.

All is not, however, lost.  You can *copy* the commits to new-and-improved commits, whose only difference from the original commits is ... well, let's take one commit as an example.  The original commit says *the files are named `src/file1`, `src/file2`, etc, and here are their contents: ... The commit was made by ____ on ____ and its parents are ...*  The new-and-improved commit says *the files are named `projects/A/src/file1`, `projects/A/src/file2`, etc., and here are their contents ... The commit was made by (same person) on (same date) and its parents are (the new-and-improved copies of the original commit's parents).*

This copying process is tedious but straightforward, and it can be done by `git filter-branch`, `git filter-repo`, and various other tools as shown in [git move directory to another repository while keeping the history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41811986/1256452) (among many other very similar questions).  Note that if you have other additional repositories whose commits—or rather, new-and-improved *copies* of commits—you'd like to have in this repository, you must decide whether to convert each set of commits one at a time, then try to make combining (merge) commits to combine them, or to write a *much fancier* filter that attempts to combine all the other repositories' commits at once.  That is, one new-and-improved commit might represent two or more "original" commits from other repositories.  This is a *much more difficult proposition* and the existing filter programs that do the simple straightforward thing do not do this for you.