# Copy/Move a folder from one repo to another repo while preserving history in Git

Tags: git, copy, repo

I have a new git repo `RepoA` with a proof of concept project in my laptop that isn't stored anywhere else and another repo `RepoB` I checked out from Azure DevOps. I just want to copy the entire project in `RepoA` into a folder in `RepoB` while preserving the history of the project from `RepoA`.  So the history for `RepoB` will display all the history entries for `RepoA` along with `RepoB`'s history.  Is this possible?

How can I do this in few steps (as opposed a mile long list of git cli commands in many SO answers).  I don't want to filter anything in `RepoA`, just copy the root folder into `RepoB` with all the history intact.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno Thanks for the link.  I tried few suggested answers but was getting errors and don't have time.  So I ended up copying the folder and pasting into RepoB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git move directory to another repository while keeping the history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811986/git-move-directory-to-another-repository-while-keeping-the-history)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

History, in a Git repository, is nothing more or less than the *commits* in the Git repository.

No commit can ever be changed.  You can, however, throw out some old set of commits in favor of some new-and-improved set of commits.  You can, at any time, add *new* commits, either by literally just adding commits, one at a time, or by using `git merge` to combine some old chain of commits with some other old chain of commits.  The latter works because `git log` *finds* commits by working backwards, one commit at a time, from more-recent commits to older commits; upon reaching a merge commit, `git log` follows *both chains* unless instructed to follow only *one chain*.

How `git log` follows both chains, or only one chain, and the way you instruct it to do one or the other, can get very complicated.  That may affect how you choose to go about adding your commits.

Other than that, though, you either use a cheap and dirty merge (with `--allow-unrelated-histories` if needed) to whack the two repositories' commits into one messy mass, or you use the other SO answers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I ended up just doing the good old copy/paste and called it a day. I've been running into lots of issues and don't have time unfortunately.  May be I will go through some of the suggested SO answers when I have time.  Plus the the commit history in the POC project is not that important if I lose it.  I'm used to Visual Studio and TortoiseGit GUI tools for git but time to time I find myself on the git cli dark side.